# What do I do for the points system count all letters?

Tags: c, scrabble

I'm making this program, it should count points for each letter just like on the scrabble game, but in my code it is skipping almost all of the letters that are located after b on the string for whatever reason.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
     char letters[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
                  'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
     int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};


     string word1 = "banana";

     int w1p = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word1); i++)
    {
        int n = 0;
        printf("%c" ,word1[i]);

        do
        {
            if (word1[i] == letters[n])
            {
                w1p = POINTS[n] + w1p;
                n++;
                printf("%c" ,word1[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                n++;
            }
        }
        while (n > 26);
    }
    printf("%i" ,w1p);
}
```

The string syntax is from the cs50 library, as I started learning C now, I'm taking some shortcuts until I get some experience.

I tried to make it run the loop again until it finished the alphabet, but it doesn't seem to work, If someone could help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: Did you also ask [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77581728/11082165)?

Comment: @Brian61354270, I don't know, it shows up as page not found.

Comment: `while (n > 26);` --> `while (n < 26);`

Comment: If `n` starts at 0 and counts up how many iterations will a loop based on `while (n > 26);` run?

Comment: Just wondering since that question was about a similar piece of code with similar syntax quirks. If there's a chance that you may have accidentally asked and deleted that question from a different account, you'll want to be sure to have the accounts merged. Otherwise you may risk having this account and any future accounts banned. Disregard if you this is your first question :)

Comment: @adabsurdum, true, just a typo from me, my bad for wasting your time

Comment: Got it, thanks for the advice @Brian61354270

Comment: You are executing the `do { } while (n > 26);` only once, because `n` always starts at `0`.  You should put `while (n < sizeof LETTERS);`

Answer (score 1):

Testing out your code it quickly became evident that the issue resided in the "do/while" loop testing criteria.

```
    int n = 0;
    printf("%c",word1[i]);

    do
    {
        if (word1[i] == letters[n])     /* Only going to be true for the letter "a" */
        {
            w1p = POINTS[n] + w1p;
            n++;
            printf("%c",word1[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            n++;
        }
    }
    while (n > 26); /* Going to execute the do loop only once each cycle as "1" is not greater than "26" */
```

The best thing to be said about "do/while" loops is that they can be tricky to use.  The way the loop is set up, the code inside the "do/while" loop will be executed once, the value of "n" will be incremented from "0" to "1", and then the "while" test will be checked.  Since "1" is not greater than "26" the loop is exited.  So that is why only the "a" character is is being picked up and three points are being accumulated.

Changing the test to "while (n < 26)" seemed to resolve the issue.  Alternatively, an inner "for" loop could also have been used as noted in the following refactored code.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char letters[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm','n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};
    char *word1 = "banana";

    int w1p = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word1); i++)
    {
        printf("%c",word1[i]);

        for (int n = 0; n< 26; n++)
        {
            if (word1[i] == letters[n])
            {
                printf("%c" ,word1[i]);
                w1p += POINTS[n];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\npoints: %d\n",w1p);
}
```

FYI, I do not have the CS50 package on my system, so I substituted a conventional method of initializing the "word1" character array.  Following was the terminal output from testing both the correction to the "do/while" loop and the refactoring to utilize an inner "for" loop.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Scrabble/bin/Release$ ./Scrabble 
bbaannaannaa
points: 8
```

Try that out.  Also, it probably would be wise to dig into some more "C" tutorials, especially as it pertains to "for" loops and "do/while" loops.

Comment: And if you can successfully include `assert('z' - 'a' == 25);` (which is true on virtually all machines that don't use EBCDIC, and those are both rare and are — or were — primarily IBM mainframes and machines emulating them), then you can calculate the index in `POINTS` without need for the `letters` array or the inner loop: `w1p += POINTS[word1[i] - 'a'];` does the job with no fuss. If the input were typed by the user instead of compiled into the program, then it would be as well to check that `word1[i]` is a lower-case letter, convert an upper-case letter to lower-case, and skip non-letters.